# Hibernate inserting row foreign key error

Tags: java, hibernate, foreign-keys

Please help me. When i try to create new row in database i receive something about foreign key FOREIGNKEY_CUSTOMER_ID. if i just edit some row it works just fine.
Here's entity:

```
    package entity;
// Generated 01.11.2011 10:03:53 by Hibernate Tools 3.2.1.GA


import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

/**
 * PurchaseOrder generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="PURCHASE_ORDER"
    ,schema="APP"
)
public class PurchaseOrder  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private int orderNum;
     private int customerId;
     private int productId;
     private Short quantity;
     private BigDecimal shippingCost;
     private Date salesDate;
     private Date shippingDate;
     private String freightCompany;

    public PurchaseOrder() {
    }


    public PurchaseOrder(int orderNum, int customerId, int productId) {
        this.orderNum = orderNum;
        this.customerId = customerId;
        this.productId = productId;
    }
    public PurchaseOrder(int orderNum, int customerId, int productId, Short quantity, BigDecimal shippingCost, Date salesDate, Date shippingDate, String freightCompany) {
       this.orderNum = orderNum;
       this.customerId = customerId;
       this.productId = productId;
       this.quantity = quantity;
       this.shippingCost = shippingCost;
       this.salesDate = salesDate;
       this.shippingDate = shippingDate;
       this.freightCompany = freightCompany;
    }

     @Id 

    @Column(name="ORDER_NUM", unique=true, nullable=false)
    public int getOrderNum() {
        return this.orderNum;
    }

    public void setOrderNum(int orderNum) {
        this.orderNum = orderNum;
    }

    @Column(name="CUSTOMER_ID", nullable=false)
    public int getCustomerId() {
        return this.customerId;
    }

    public void setCustomerId(int customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }

    @Column(name="PRODUCT_ID", nullable=false)
    public int getProductId() {
        return this.productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(int productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    @Column(name="QUANTITY")
    public Short getQuantity() {
        return this.quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(Short quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    @Column(name="SHIPPING_COST", precision=12)
    public BigDecimal getShippingCost() {
        return this.shippingCost;
    }

    public void setShippingCost(BigDecimal shippingCost) {
        this.shippingCost = shippingCost;
    }
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name="SALES_DATE", length=10)
    public Date getSalesDate() {
        return this.salesDate;
    }

    public void setSalesDate(Date salesDate) {
        this.salesDate = salesDate;
    }
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name="SHIPPING_DATE", length=10)
    public Date getShippingDate() {
        return this.shippingDate;
    }

    public void setShippingDate(Date shippingDate) {
        this.shippingDate = shippingDate;
    }

    @Column(name="FREIGHT_COMPANY", length=30)
    public String getFreightCompany() {
        return this.freightCompany;
    }

    public void setFreightCompany(String freightCompany) {
        this.freightCompany = freightCompany;
    }




}


  <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 01.11.2011 10:04:03 by Hibernate Tools 3.2.1.GA -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="entity.PurchaseOrder" table="PURCHASE_ORDER" schema="APP">
        <id name="orderNum" type="int">
            <column name="ORDER_NUM" />
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>
        <property name="customerId" type="int">
            <column name="CUSTOMER_ID" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="productId" type="int">
            <column name="PRODUCT_ID" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="quantity" type="java.lang.Short">
            <column name="QUANTITY" />
        </property>
        <property name="shippingCost" type="big_decimal">
            <column name="SHIPPING_COST" precision="12" />
        </property>
        <property name="salesDate" type="date">
            <column name="SALES_DATE" length="10" />
        </property>
        <property name="shippingDate" type="date">
            <column name="SHIPPING_DATE" length="10" />
        </property>
        <property name="freightCompany" type="string">
            <column name="FREIGHT_COMPANY" length="30" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

my code:

```
 Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            Transaction tr = session.beginTransaction();
            PurchaseOrder o = new PurchaseOrder();
o.setFreightCompany("Companytest");
                    session.save(o);
                    tr.commit();
```

errors i receive:

```
Hibernate: select max(ORDER_NUM) from PURCHASE_ORDER
Hibernate: insert into APP.PURCHASE_ORDER (CUSTOMER_ID, PRODUCT_ID, QUANTITY, SHIPPING_COST, SALES_DATE, SHIPPING_DATE, FREIGHT_COMPANY, ORDER_NUM) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
ноя 01, 2011 10:45:21 AM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
WARNING: SQL Error: -1, SQLState: 23503
ноя 01, 2011 10:45:21 AM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
SEVERE: INSERT в таблице 'PURCHASE_ORDER' вызывает нарушение ограничения чужого ключа 'FOREIGNKEY_CUSTOMER_ID' для ключа (0).  Произведен откат оператора.
ноя 01, 2011 10:45:21 AM org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener performExecutions
SEVERE: Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [entity.PurchaseOrder]
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2267)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2660)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:250)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
    at xml.XmlRead.main(XmlRead.java:69)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: INSERT в таблице 'PURCHASE_ORDER' вызывает нарушение ограничения чужого ключа 'FOREIGNKEY_CUSTOMER_ID' для ключа (0).  Произведен откат оператора.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.NonBatchingBatcher.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatcher.java:23)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2247)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: INSERT в таблице 'PURCHASE_ORDER' вызывает нарушение ограничения чужого ключа 'FOREIGNKEY_CUSTOMER_ID' для ключа (0).  Произведен откат оператора.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.completeExecute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parseEXCSQLSTTreply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.readExecute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.StatementReply.readExecute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetPreparedStatement.readExecute_(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.readExecute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.flowExecute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateX(Unknown Source)
    ... 14 more

org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [entity.PurchaseOrder]
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2267)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2660)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:250)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
    at xml.XmlRead.main(XmlRead.java:69)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: INSERT в таблице 'PURCHASE_ORDER' вызывает нарушение ограничения чужого ключа 'FOREIGNKEY_CUSTOMER_ID' для ключа (0).  Произведен откат оператора.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.NonBatchingBatcher.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatcher.java:23)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2247)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: INSERT в таблице 'PURCHASE_ORDER' вызывает нарушение ограничения чужого ключа 'FOREIGNKEY_CUSTOMER_ID' для ключа (0).  Произведен откат оператора.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.completeExecute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parseEXCSQLSTTreply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.readExecute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.StatementReply.readExecute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetPreparedStatement.readExecute_(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.readExecute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.flowExecute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateX(Unknown Source)
    ... 14 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your statement fails because the `customerId` property is not set, but you have a not-null constraint on the corresponding database row. Try to provide a valid number as customerId.

```
int customerId = 1;
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
Transaction tr = session.beginTransaction();
PurchaseOrder o = new PurchaseOrder();
o.setFreightCompany("Companytest");
o.setCustomerId(customerId);
                session.save(o);
                tr.commit();
```

I am not quite shure where the misleading String "FOREIGNKEY" comes from since there is no foreign key relationship present that could be violated, did you configure some sort of column prefix at some other place in the code?

Comment: thank you so much for reply. i still get this exception even witho.setCustomerId(customerId);
. i didnt configured any prefixes. in actual database it says FOREIGNKEY_CUSTOMER_ID FOREIGNKEY_PPRODUCT_ID. do this mean i have foreign relationships? sorry i dont speak english really well. please help if you can.

Comment: Do you have other tables in your Project? For example if you have a `CUSTOMER` table, that one could have a foreign key relation towards your `PURCHASE_ORDER` Table and will fail your query if you are referencing an nonexistent customer?

Comment: thanks for answer again. Could you please rephrase i dont understand.

Comment: i got what you mean. thank you so much for help. you are awesome. its all works now.